Relation between efq, DS, DNE, LEM
I am contemplating on the relation between the above formulae schema in the setting of minimal logic (which is just classical logic stripped of efq and DNE; thus, $\bot$ is just some constant formula) using natural deduction. Note that DS stands for Disjunctive Syllogism.
Firstly, I present the relations I believe I have proven (I will gladly present my proofs if needed1):

DNE $\implies$ LEM $\implies$ DS $\iff$ efq
LEM + DS $\implies$ DNE

But then, this means that LEM $\iff$ DNE, without any "explicit" need of efq, which refutes a convincing negative stance that DNE requires LEM + efq, leading to obvious confusion.
Question: I am not at all experienced in logic, and my proofs might be erroneous. Thus, if someone can confirm if the above relations are indeed correct in minimal logic, I will be able to sleep alright. I'd also appreciate if you can say something about the correctness of the other implications.

1Let me show how I seem to have proven LEM $\implies$ DS:
Assume $A\vee B$ and $\neg A$. Goal is $B$. Since we have LEM, the goal becomes $\neg\neg B$. Thus, assume $\neg B$ with the goal of $\bot$. Now that we have $\neg A$ and $\neg B$, we may conclude $\neg(A\vee B)$ (this version of De Margan is easily proven in minimal logic). Denoting $A\vee B$ by $P$, we thus have $P\wedge\neg P$, and since we have $\neg(P\wedge\neg P)$ (again easily proven in minimal logic), we can conclude $\bot$.

Worth noting that LEM => DNE doesn't hold in minimal logic, so your proof is actually that DNE => DS (at least if the details go through)

@S.C. This means that my presented proof of LEM $\implies$ DS must be flawed (because LEM + DS does imply DNE in minimal). But I can't seem to find any flaw...

What I'm pointing out is that you say you're using LEM when you replace the goal of $B$ with $\lnot \lnot B$, but that's actually DNE, not LEM

Aarghhh! That was embarrassing. I did use DNE, while I had intended to use LEM.

In minimal logic, $A \vee B, \neg A \vdash \neg \neg B$, but also $A \vee B, \neg A \nvdash B$.
Adding the LEM doesn't help here, because you also need EFQ for DNE with the LEM.
$\begin{array}{|c|lr|}1. & A\vee B & Prem. \\ 2. & \neg A & Prem. \\ & \begin{array}{|c|lr|}3. & \neg B & SM\neg I \\ & \begin{array}{|c|lr|}4. & A & SM\to I \\ 5. & \bot & \bot I,4,2\end{array}\\ 6. & A \to \bot & \to I,4-5 \\ & \begin{array}{|c|lr|}7. & B & SM\to I \\ 8. & \bot & \bot I,7,3\end{array}\\ 9. & B \to \bot & \to I,7-8 \\ 10. & \bot & \vee E,1,6,9 \end{array}\\ 11. & \neg \neg B & \neg I,3-10\\ \end{array}$
For DNE to work given this minimal result, you'll need to find a way to derive $\neg \neg B \vdash B$. The principal way to do that is to add an axiom or rule to intuitionistic logic, which will have explosion (or an EFQ rule), as well.
The LEM, alone, does not guarantee DNE, so the following reasoning was flawed:

Assume $A \vee B$ and $\neg A$. Goal is B. Since we have LEM, the goal becomes $\neg \neg B$.

Instead, the only attainable minimal-logic derivation is $\neg \neg B$, and the LEM plays no part in it.
